# C++ function pointer to function that takes a template as an arguement

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, function-pointers

How do you do a function pointer to a function that takes a template as its argument?
I'm trying to make a pointer to this function

```
template<typename BaseType>
int indexOfLargest(const BaseType list[], int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > endIndex)
        return -1;

    int indexOfMax = startIndex;
    for (int index = startIndex + 1; index < endIndex; index++)
        if (list[index] > list[indexOfMax])
            indexOfMax = index;
    return indexOfMax;
}
```

and this function

```
template<typename BaseType>
int indexOfSmallest(const BaseType list[], int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > endIndex)
        return -1;

    int indexOfMin = startIndex;
    for (int index = startIndex + 1; index < endIndex; index++)
        if (list[index] < list[indexOfMin])
            indexOfMin = index;
    return indexOfMin;
}
```

So I can avoid doing an if statement on each iteration.

```
template<typename A0, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4>
void sortArrayData(A0 a0[], A1 a1[], A2 a2[], A3 a3[], A4 a4[],
        const int recordCount, int order) {
    int indexOfNext;

    for (int index = 0; index < recordCount - 1; index++) {
        if (order == 1)
            indexOfNext = indexOfSmallest(a0, index, recordCount);
        else
            indexOfNext = indexOfLargest(a0, index, recordCount);

        swap_v(a0[index], a0[indexOfNext]);
        swap_v(a1[index], a1[indexOfNext]);
        swap_v(a2[index], a2[indexOfNext]);
        swap_v(a3[index], a3[indexOfNext]);
        swap_v(a4[index], a4[indexOfNext]);
    }

}
```

> -- additional I could not find any answers for this online or from fellow programmers.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways. You could let the compiler figure it out for you:

```
template<typename A0, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4, typename F>
void sortArrayData(A0 a0[], 
                   A1 a1[], 
                   A2 a2[], 
                   A3 a3[], 
                   A4 a4[],
                   const int recordCount, 
                   F indexFunc)
{
    int indexOfNext;

    for (int index = 0; index < recordCount - 1; index++) {
        indexOfNext = indexFunc(a0, index, recordCount);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or you could specify the signature directly either as a function or as a std::function.

```
template<typename A0, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4>
void sortArrayData(A0 a0[], 
                   A1 a1[], 
                   A2 a2[], 
                   A3 a3[], 
                   A4 a4[],
                   const int recordCount, 
                   std::function<int (A0, int, int)> indexFunc)
{
    int indexOfNext;

    for (int index = 0; index < recordCount - 1; index++) {
        indexOfNext = indexFunc(a0, index, recordCount);
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can also declare a local variable for the function:

```
template<typename A0, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4>
void sortArrayData(A0 a0[], 
                   A1 a1[], 
                   A2 a2[], 
                   A3 a3[], 
                   A4 a4[],
                   const int recordCount, 
                   int order)
{
    std::function<int (A0, int, int)> indexFunc = (order == 1) ? (indexOfSmallest) : (indexOfSmallest);

    int indexOfNext;

    for (int index = 0; index < recordCount - 1; index++) {
        indexOfNext = indexFunc(a0, index, recordCount);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to declare it within the function?

Comment: Add a third example with a local function variable. Though I don't think that this will be a huge performance improvement because it trades a indirection for the branch. Processors are quite good at predicting branches, so I recommend to profile it.

Comment: Well all of this is good for C++11 but does not work for the older stuff

Comment: The first template parameter solution works on C++03 too, this is how STL algorithms work. Instead of std::function, you could use boost::function on C++03, define a function pointer or use the first version with the template parameter and define an additional overload with order which calls it.

Answer (score 3):

A function template is not a function. You cannot form a pointer to a function template or pass one as an argument to a function. However you don't seem to really need any of it for this task. You do this

```
template<typename A0, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4>
void sortArrayData(A0 a0[], A1 a1[], A2 a2[], A3 a3[], A4 a4[],
        const int recordCount, 
        int (*func)(A0[], int, int)) { ...
```

and then just pass `indexOfLargest` or `indexOfSmallest` as if it was a function. The system will automatically select the right instantiation. A simplified example goes like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class x> void xxx (x xx){cout << xx << endl; }

void foo(void (*f)(int)) {f(5);}

int main() {
    foo(xxx);
    return 0;
}
```